# How to put partners logo in footer?

Tags: css, layout, footer

How can I put a partner's logo in  my site's footer ([Like this](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2j10aox&s=8#.VCuqI_mSySo))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have them below the bottom links (About Us, Services) .. then look at your `<div id="bottom-footer">` and there is a container called `<div class="site-info">`.

Just add your own container before the closing `</div>` if you need not that many logos (2/3rd).

Else try to add your container after `<div class="copyright">'s closing </div>`.

Comment: I will create new div and put this code <img class="footer-image" src="myImage.jpg"> inside the div?

Comment: Yes, correctly. Then you can set their horizontal spacing like:  `.footer-image { margin-right: 20px; } .footer-image:last-child { margin-right:0px; }`with css.

Answer (score 1):

Well, simply use the `img` tag in html. What the problem with that?

```
<footer>
<img class="footer-image" src="myImage.jpg">
</footer>
```

And if you want them all aligned wrap them with a `div` and add style to that dive as `display: inline-flex`

Answer (score 0):

html

```css
    ul {
      list-style-type: none;
    }
    li {
      display: inline-block;
      margin: according to the image size;
    }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="your_image.png">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="your_image.png">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="your_image.png">
  </li>
</ul>
```